# Unable to cache repeated requests that are needed for different services/components

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I'm working on a project where there are multiple instances of data that need to be displayed to the user.
In this particular case, each instance of data multiple requests to be done to the backend.
This means that for the data set UserDetails, I need to query the endpoints getUser and getSigns.
However, these endpoints are also used for other things, so I need to avoid making the same request multiple times. The trigger for this data is a button click (for simplicity), however in reality I don't know have something so simple to work on.

A conditional that was imposed was to avoid the extensive use of rxjs. What do I mean by extensive?
They should be contained to 2/3 services, and converted to promises when possible. Can't use rxjs in the component.

I created a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-w6eupm?file=src%2Fservices%2Fhttp-wrapper.service.ts) with the issue.

I was able to do the majority of the work, however, I'm facing an issue where I'm not able to cancel previous button click requests (I can't use rxjs on the component itself due to the previous restriction).

This means that if the user clicks while another request is pending (don't know how long each takes), I end up in a situation where they all rapidly update (confusion for the user).

Would appreciate help on this.

Tried to add a subject to the http-wrapper service and perform a switch map on it.
It canceled ongoing requests, but it time I would push a new request, it would append them.
So I would click once, get one request, click twice, get two requests (instead of just one), click three times and get three requests, and so on. Also tried to use rxjs share and multicast but was unsuccessful.

In the end, I want a way to make multiple requests, cache them to avoid requesting duplicate info and share them when different services need the same data.

Answer (score 0):

This is a classic problem in frontend world.

What you're looking for is a state management library where you decouple the fetching of the data from data consumption itself.

As an example that I use myself a lot, [ngrx](https://ngrx.io/guide/store) is a really good state management library. You may have heard of "redux". It reuses the same core principles and basically wraps everything within observables instead of using callbacks, which is a very good match for angular and async pipe. You've got plenty of others like [ngxs](https://www.ngxs.io/), [elf](https://ngneat.github.io/elf/) and others.

The main idea if we use ngrx as an example here would be to use an effect to trigger data fetching when you're on a given route, populate the store with the answer and then in your component read data from the store.

This way, reading data doesn't mean you'll trigger any kind of fetching and you can have a fine grain fetching strategy exactly the way you want.

Using [selectors](https://ngrx.io/guide/store/selectors) you can then mix, split, merge, compose your data from the store the way you want and expose that to the view easily.

If you're interested, read ngrx documentation, it's really good. (and maybe first compare with other solutions to see the one you prefer before using ngrx straight away, it's all down to a personal preference for the syntax/overall idea).